# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 while removing item from GridView

Tags: android, gridview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-gridview

I'm trying to delete a GridView's multiple selected items on a Button click event .
But it's throwing this error `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Can someone help me how to solve this issues^

The Error log

```
12-07 13:51:21.006  14416-14416/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 14416
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AddPost$2.onClick(AddPost.java:244)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Activity code

```
imgDeleteImagesFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = gridAdapter.getCheckedItems();
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++)
                    {

                            fileName.remove(i);

                    }gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
            });
```

Here is my GridView Adapter class

```
 class GridView_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
        public GridView_Adapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        }

            public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
            ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i=0;i<fileName.size();i++) {
                if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    mTempArry.add(fileName.get(i));
                }}
            return mTempArry;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return fileName.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
           ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_post_grid_item_layout, parent , false);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName.get(position));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                 {
                     mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
                     int pos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                     if (!buttonView.isChecked())
                     {
                         picsName.remove((String) fileName.get(pos));
                     }
                     else if(buttonView.isChecked())
                     {
                         if (!picsName.contains((String) fileName.get(pos))) {
                             picsName.add((String) fileName.get(pos));

                         }
                     }
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
             });


            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cycle causes this error, because it removes the lower index first.
It should be the opposite: starting from the highest index remove that one and come back to the lower index.

Something like this:

```
int len = selectedItems.size() - 1; // Precalculate it once, so that the cycle runs faster
for (int i = len; i > 1; i--)
{

        fileName.remove(i);

}
```

Comment: Image is not delete .

Comment: The error doesn't show up anymore - which fixes your previous issue. Now this is another question.

Comment: thanks for the reply . Image deleted properly but why check boxes appear as it is . Why not remove check box also ?

Comment: Because you are only removing the file. You did not write any code to remove the checkboxes.

Comment: Can you guide me how to remove check box also ?

Comment: I guess you should remove `buttonView` after `picsName.remove((String) fileName.get(pos));`? Or is it `holder.checkbox` which has to be removed. I should make a couple of trials on the live code.

Comment: I tried this way =  else if(buttonView.isChecked())
                     {
                         if (!picsName.contains((String) fileName.get(pos))) {
                             picsName.add((String) fileName.get(pos));
                             fileName.remove(buttonView);
                         }
                     }
                     notifyDataSetChanged();    Still not remove check boxes .

Comment: No. It's not what I meant. Anyway. This is becoming too broad, for a single question.

Comment: int len = selectedItems.size() - 1;
                    for (int i = len; i > 1; i--)
                    {
                      //  vh.checkbox.setTag(i);

                        //fileName.remove(vh.checkbox.setTag(i));
                        fileName.remove(i);
                        fileName.remove((Integer) vh.checkbox.getTag(i));


                    }gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  This is also not working for check box.

Comment: Thanks . At least images are deleted properly .